# /sd-ext gets suddenly remounted read only during work

Tags: external-sd, app2sd, mount, s2e

I have an HTC Desire with cyanogenmod 7.2 (with pdroid patch) and with an partitioned microSD card (first: FAT, second: ext3).

The second partition gets automatically mounted read/writeable as `/sd-ext` as it should be.
I'm using S2E to store my apps and the app data on this ext3 partition.  The `mount` command shows me that the ext3 partition is not only mounted to `/sd-ext` but also to `/data/app` and `/data/data`.  All of them are mounted read/writeable.

My first question:  Is it normal and secure that multiple directories are bound to the same partition?  Are there no conflicts?

In the beginning everything worked fine.  I could install and use my apps without problems.  But after a while more and more apps begun to crash and I always had to restart my phone to get rid of those crashes again.  I discovered that the crashes where caused by a read only data partition.  In fact all the directories `/sd-ext`, `/data/data`, and `/data/apps` where suddenly mounted read only.

My second question: Why does Android sometimes remount my ext3 partition in read only mode while I work with my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get rid of the filesystem corruptions.  I configured S2E so that it mounts the ext3 partition only to `/sd-ext` and `/data/apps`.  Since then the partition is not remounted read only anymore.  So it seems that the simultaneous write access to the different mount points of the ext3 partition (`/data/apps` and `/data/data`) caused the filesystem corruptions.

Answer (score 1):

Remounting as read-only is an action taken by Linux-based operating systems (including Android) in case of errors accessing the filesystem. In this case it probably indicates that your micro-SD has been (partially) corrupted. There are several possible causes of corruption like this:

- Using the phone as a USB mass storage device and unplugging it while a write is in progress
- The phone rebooting while an app or the OS is writing to the filesystem
- A bug in the ext3 driver in the ROM you're using
- A physical error on the SD card due to excessive heat or cold, mechanical shock, manufacturing defects, strong magnetic fields, &c.

Whatever the root cause, try plugging your card into a card reader on a PC and checking it for filesystem errors (for example, using `fsck` on a GNU/Linux box).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right with the FS corruption. I verified it with fsck. Unfortunately, I could not identify the cause for the corruption. I checked your points. 1 and 2 are definitely not the cause in my case. 3 is pretty unlikely I think. Regarding 4 I checked the FS on my PC. But badblocks could find any hardware errors.